# Unable to receive TCP data on particular IP

Tags: sockets, tcp, server, client, systypes.h

I am trying to implement TCP client, server program in C on Linux system. Here are my codes.

Client Source Code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *address;

   // Create socket
   int client_socket;
   client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   // Set - Up Server Address
   struct sockaddr_in server_address;
   server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server_address.sin_port = htons(8001);
   inet_aton(address, &server_address.sin_addr.s_addr);

   // Connect to the server 
   int connect_stat;
   connect_stat = connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
   if(connect_stat == -1)
        printf("Not Connected\n");
   else
        printf(" Connected \n");
   // Recieve from server
   char response[256];
   recv(client_socket, &server_address, sizeof(server_address), 0);

   // Printing the Response data
   printf("Data Recieved : %s\n",response);

   // Destroy the socket
   close(client_socket);

   return 0;
}
```

Server Source Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Address
    char *address;
    address = argv[1];

    // Create message to send
    char message[256] = "Connection Established";

    // Create server socket
    int server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Set - Up Server Address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(8001);
    inet_aton(address, &server_address.sin_addr.s_addr);

    // Bind it to an IP and PORT
    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    // Start listenting on address
    listen(server_socket, 5);

    // Start accepting the clients;
    int client_socket;
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);

    // Send some data back to client
    send(client_socket, message, sizeof(message), 0);

    // Close the socket
    close(server_socket);
    close(client_socket); 

    return 0;
}
```

On passing an IP like 192.168.1.xxx to both client and server, server starts waiting for the clients but client always show not connected and thus no data received.

Client output :

```
root@kali:/home/mayank/Desktop/tcp_chat# ./tcp_client 192.168.1.111
Not Connected
Data Recieved :
```

But if i use INADDR_ANY instead of specific IP, it works. I know INADDR_ANY basically means it binds to all IP address, but why it is not binding to specific IP address which i want. Any suggestions, where i am wrong.

Comment: Check the `errno` when you print "Not Connected" .

Comment: After including errno.h in my program i got following output
`root@kali:/home/mayank/Desktop/tcp_chat# ./tcp_Client 192.168.1.100`
`Not Connected`
`Errno : 88`
`Data Recieved :`

Comment: error code 88 is `ENOTSOCK`, which means you are calling a socket function on a file descriptor that is not a valid socket. Most of your code is not performing any error handling at all, like making sure that `socket()` is not returning a value < 0.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `inet_aton()`, you can also use

```
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("IP address");
```

And use `perror()` after every function, like

```
client_socket = socket(...);
if (client_socket == -1)
    perror("socket");
```

Comment: perror output says "Socket operation on non-socket" and i even replaced inet_aton with inet_addr() but the same problem still persists

Comment: On the client side, `address` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing any error checking, except on the `connect()` call.  For example, you are getting an `ENOTSOCK` error because you are not checking whether `socket()` succeeds or fails.

Beyond that, on the client side, this statement:

```
inet_aton(address, &server_address.sin_addr.s_addr);
```

Should be this instead:

```
inet_aton(address, &server_address.sin_addr);
```

`inet_aton()` expects a pointer to a `struct in_addr`, but you are passing it a pointer to a `uint32_t` instead.  In fact, the original code should not have even compiled because of that.

But, more importantly, your `address` variable is **uninitialized**, so you are passing a bad memory pointer to `inet_aton()`, and not checking its return value for failure.

Even if you could connect to the server, you are also passing the wrong output buffer to `recv()`, so you would end up writing garbage to the console.

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: %s <IPv4 address>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    // Set - Up Server Address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address = {0};
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(8001);
    if (inet_aton(argv[1], &server_address.sin_addr) != 0)
    {
        printf("invalid IPv4 address specified\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Create socket
    int client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (client_socket == -1)
    {
        perror("socket() failed");
        return 0;
    }

    // Connect to the server 
    if (connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Not Connected");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connected\n");

        // Receive from server
        char response[256];
        int numRecvd = recv(client_socket, response, sizeof(response), 0);

        // Printing the Response data
        if (numRecvd == -1)
            perror("recv() failed");
        else if (numRecvd == 0)
            printf("Disconnected by server\n");
        else
            printf("Data Received: [%d] %.*s\n", numRecvd, numRecvd, response);
    }

    // Destroy the socket
    close(client_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Set - Up Server Address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address = {0};
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(8001);
    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        if (inet_aton(argv[1], &server_address.sin_addr) != 0)
        {
            printf("invalid IPv4 address specified\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
        server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // Create message to send
    char message[256] = "Connection Established";

    // Create server socket
    int server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (server_socket == -1)
    {
        perror("socket() failed");
        return 0;
    }

    // Bind it to an IP and PORT
    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind() failed");
    }

    // Start listenting on address
    else if (listen(server_socket, 5) == -1)
    {
        perror("listen() failed");
    }

    // Start accepting the clients
    else
    {
        int client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, 0);
        if (client_socket == -1)
        {
            perror("accept() failed");
        }
        else
        {
            // Send some data back to client
            int numSent = send(client_socket, message, sizeof(message), 0);
            if (numSent == -1)
                perror("send() failed");
            else
                printf("Data Sent: [%d] %.*s\n", numSent, numSent, message);

            // Close the socket
            close(client_socket); 
        }
    }

    // Destroy the socket
    close(server_socket);

    return 0;
}
```